# is there a way to preload low quality in MPEG Dash or HLS so there is always something to play?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I created HLS manifests and DASH manifests with different resolutions and bitrates.

The videos almost always starts low quality,  then picks up quality/resolution.

But later, if Internet speed drops,  the video stops because its playing the hi resolution video.

is there a way to preload low quality in MPEG DASH or HLS so there is always something to play ?

Edit:  I have the video preloaded.  its not live streaming but once it starts playing,  I am looking for a consistent stream, even if that means sacrificing quality.

Comment: Try increasing segment duration. Default must be two seconds for ffmpeg. Apart from that, preloading future content depends to your video player's implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have the video preloaded. its not live streaming'? Do you mean you download the entire video before you start playback, or do you mean you just download the start of the video and then start playback, streaming the remainder?

Comment: It's not a live stream.  It's like Youtube or Netflix,  where the video already exists.   MPEG Dash and HLS help the user play it right away.
What I mean by preloading is that I want (if possible) to preload for example all the video in low res,  and if the bandwidth is enough for more resolution, then good,  but if its not,  I have the low res already in place to make sure the user sees everything.

Comment: In theory it wounds like that would be possible - your manifest could be modified to have the URL for the lowest resolution stream point to the local copy and the other resolutions to the online locations. You would need some sort of local server to 'serve' the low res segments also. Plus you would need to download and store the low res segments before hand. Probably quite a lot of work to implement, but sounds possible theoretically. Interesting use case!